# MVC model Design

Tags: php, mysql, model

I have a question regarding the use of a model i want to build. I cant see the problems yet but i think people who already programmed some more than me knows the restrictions.

I want a model that has students, teachers, parents and members

What I have now i a table for students one for teachers and so on.

I want to know if it is possible and if it is what are the restrictions to use one table named Users and then make a user a member of a usergroup.

Example User A would be a member of students but could also be a member of a parent and could also be a teacher. If i split the tables it is not so difficult.

But if I put them in one table Users, how will I make a table where I put the link between a parent and student. It would look like a table parent_student where I add the relation_id and two times the User_id this is not possible because I wont know who the parent is and who the child is. I know I can make a parent_id and a student_id and then insert the user_id in it. But will that have any problems in the future.

Comment: It is possible. I suggest you go over over the fundamentals of relational databases particularly junction tables and table joins.

Comment: The above comment is spot on - relational database design is what you want - [This should help you along](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model)